# Ignoring / skipping known or all subordinated tags with XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, tags

I am using XPath with Hpple / libxml2 for parsing HTML in iOS / iPhone OS. I now want to ignore a certain tag like the bold tag `<b>` when parsing the document:

For instance from the code

`<div>foo<b>bar</b></div>`

the strings "foo" and "bar" should be selected and concatenated resulting in "foobar".

It appeared to me after viewing related requests that they possibly would not solve this issue but it's absolutely possible that I am wrong. If so, please let me know and give an example using the example above.

Thank you.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution and explanation. :)

Comment: I'm a bit confused regarding your use of the word namespace. The `<b>` tag is simply a tag, with a specific meaning in whatever markup language is being used (presumably XHTML in your case). Namespaces make sure tags from multiple markup languages can be used together without ambiguities regarding their semantics.

Comment: @SnuggleUp: the improper terminology makes this question unclear.

Comment: Oh, I am really sorry for this! Indeed I used the wrong term for what I meant. I actually did not concern myself with XML or other markup languages much yet, only when I needed it superficially like now. I have corrected it.

Comment: @SnuggleUp: I meant parse/traverse/serialize/render and tag/element...

Comment: To follow up: "Parsing" an XML document turns it into a tree of nodes (element nodes, attribute nodes, text nodes, etc). An XPath expression navigates that tree of nodes, selecting some of them, or computing properties such as their string value (which is what you want in this case). So you don't use XPath to parse the XML, you use XPath to find your way around the parsed XML. The original XML contains tags, and the parser uses these to construct element nodes. For example, the element node `b` corresponds to two tags in the source XML, the start tag `<b>` and the end tag `</b>`

Comment: @Michael Kay: Even though I might have used the wrong phrase, I am aware of the process you describe, thank you, anyway. So you would suggest to use the terms selection and concatenation of string values of XML nodes or similar terms?

Comment: @Alejandro: In fact, I doubt that this terminological vagueness makes my question unclear, since my simple example clarifies my concern which was well answered.

Comment: @Michael Kay: Really excellent comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
string(/*)
```

**When evaluated against the provided XML document**:

```
<div>foo<b>bar</b></div>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
foobar
```

**Explanation**:

As per the [**XPath 1.0 W3C specification**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#element-nodes):

"*The string-value of an element node is the concatenation of the string-values of all text node descendants of the element node in document order*"

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response, I will try it out asap! ;)

Comment: Ccan u show it in some example?
i mean `NSArray *googleDescriptions = [googleParser search:@"//div[@class='s']"];` cause for `NSArray *googleDescriptions = [googleParser search:@"//div[@class='s'][string(/*)]"];`
it returns the same as expression w\o string function