# How to select something with its tags? And 1 more question about tag ignoring

Tags: iphone, objective-c, parsing, xpath, hpple

i have to parse google and other search systems search results, and i want to take something with tag, for example i have:

```
<span class="tl">
<h3 class="r">
<a class="l noline" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','AFQjCNE3QDnLsIkujVElxf1vT7LocQ-YYw','','0CCQQFjAA')" target="_blank" href="http://l2.ru/">
<em>Lineage</em>
2. Oficial servers l2, la2,
<em>lineage</em>
2.
</a>
</h3>
<button class="vspib"></button>
</span>
```

and i want to take all inner content of  tag, including , like

```
<a class="l noline" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','AFQjCNE3QDnLsIkujVElxf1vT7LocQ-YYw','','0CCQQFjAA')" target="_blank" href="http://l2.ru/">
<em>Lineage</em>
2. Oficial servers l2, la2,
<em>lineage</em>
2.
</a>
```

something like

```
TFHpple *googleParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:googleData];
NSArray *linksWithItsNames = [googleParser search:@"//span[@class='tl'/h3[@class='r']"];
TFHppleElement *googleLinkWithItsName = [linksWithItsNames objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *googleFirstLink = [googleLinkWithItsName content];
[myWebView loadHTMLString:googleFirstLink baseURL:requestURL];
```

And in the end i want to show in my WebView link with its name, that contains in  (so i want to ignore all b, em, br etc. tags inside ), and with its @href.

I just saw 1 question - [Ignoring / skipping known or all subordinated tags with XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197669/ignoring-skipping-known-or-all-subordinated-tags-with-xpath) but don't understand how should i ignore inner tags and how can i take inner text with its tags as a string.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[TouchXML](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchXML): an xml parser that will let you access any tag you want.